# Left-hand side priority

Tags: javascript

I was thinking about declaring vars in JS, when a doubt arose. What's the priority of setting up two vars' value at the same time? See:

```
var a = 1,
b = 1;
```

With this code, `a` is declared before `b`. But what about this code

```
var a = b = 1;
```

Which one does receive the value first? `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is evaluated as

```
var a = (b = 1);
```

Hence, `b` gets the value first.

Note that this differs from the first snippet: If not already in global scope, `b` will become a global variable (if it was not declared before). This would cause an error in strict mode.

A formal description can be found in the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.2).